# Javascript function to capitalize the first letter of each word

Tags: javascript, each, cpu-word, capitalize

I am new to javascript so I wrote my first useful function.

```
FUNCTION NAME capFirstLetter()
Converts the first letter of each word in a string to uppercase.
Using the the letter "l" as the second function parameter the function will convert only the letter of the first word to uppercase.
```

If it has short comings of any kind please leave me a comment!

```
function capFirstLetter(string,capFirstOnly) {
    var i, c = "";

    if (capFirstOnly == "l") {
        var str = string.toLowerCase().trim();
        c = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
        return(c);
    } else {            
        c = string.charAt(0).toUpperCase().trim();
        for (i = 1; i < string.length; i++ ) {
            if (string.charAt(i) == " ") {
                c = c + string.charAt(i);
                c = c + string.charAt(i + 1).toUpperCase();
                i++;
            } else {c = c + string.charAt(i).toLowerCase();} ;
        };

        return(c);
    };
};
```

Comment: It seems that this post belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should first trim then get the first char like `string.trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase();` otherwise it will not uppercase first letter if there is whitespace at the beginning.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. There are also [*many similar questions with answers*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+capitalise+words).

Comment: That is a good point, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reg exps make this world better :-)

```
function convert(s,capFirstOnly) {       
   return s.replace(capFirstOnly ? /\b\w/ : /\b\w/g, function(a) {return a.toUpperCase(); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use this:

```
str="Javascript function to capitalize the first letter of each word";
    s=str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
alert(s);
```

Comment: OP code use uppercase first letter in every word not only first letter in a string.

Comment: Did you just do that whole thing in 3 or so lines of code?

Comment: If so thats amazing!

Comment: Is it helpful? If so, please accept my answer & help others too.